# Удаление элемента из коллекции при выборе его в ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

У меня в VM есть поле, где хранится коллекция значений, которые отображаются в ComboBox.

Так у меня есть второй, который хранить некоторые значения.

Далее, я все вот так вот привязываю:

```
       <StackPanel>
            <Label>Настройка привязок результата работы алгоритма</Label>
            <ListView MinHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding FieldBindings}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Item.Name}" MinWidth="200"></Label>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel},
                                Path=DataContext.AvailableColumns}" DisplayMemberPath="ColumnName"></ComboBox>
                        </UniformGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
```

Все работает, но есть одно НО... Я хочу, чтобы при выборе значения в каком элементе списка, оно удалялось и не могло быть выбрано.

По идее, я должен как-то поймать событие выбора и удалить это значение из пула. Как это сделать по MVVMски?

Comment: Прибиндить `SelectedItem` у комбобокса к свойству внутри элемента, и в сеттере делать то что нужно.

Comment: Хм... Должно работать. А если мне еще это значение параллельно положить еще в Item.Value в списке?

Comment: Т.е я в VM должен понять, что произошел выбор из ComboBox, чтобы выполнить фильтрацию источника данных, а так же положить его значение непосредственно в Item.

Comment: Что-то типа того. Кстати, если не сталкивались с `ICollectionView` для фильтрации, попробуйте применить.